# Raspberry Pi bluetooth tether to android phone for internet

Tags: ssh, android, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, tethering

I want to tether my Android phone to my raspberry pi to share Wi-Fi connection between them so I can easily open an ssh on my phone from the Pi. I got Bluetooth paired, my phone is set to share internet over a Bluetooth tether, but the Pi will not connect to the phone, claiming 'no usable services'. I assume there is software on the Pi I need to modify? I have a raspberry pi model 3b+ running the latest Rasbian, The phone is running Android 6.0(marshmallow, I think.) Tethering via USB cord works perfectly, but I would rather go wireless, and Ad-Hoc Wi-Fi is not an option, so I would prefer bluetooth, all help appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

This video should help you. Just make keep in mind that you should be able to easily turn on Bluetooth tethering on your phone in the settings.

https://youtu.be/4Ac0wc-f9HI

Comment: Answers cannot be just a link to a video, and should stand on their own. You should at least summarize the important points in the video.